# Make value type behave as reference

Tags: c#, reference, value-type, boxing

What is the best practice to be able to assign values to value type via "reference"? In my case I need this to give possibility to assign values to ints, floats etc through out the in-app console. I dont want to give a reference to an object containing the value type as this wont make my console manager generic, and adding new commands will be a nightmare. Also I cannot use pointers, as unsafe mode is impossible in my case.

Cause my little understanding of CLR, I tried something like this:

```
int i = 1;
object o = i;
o = (object) 5;
Console.WriteLine(i);// prints original value of i, 1. I expected 5;
```

So it didnt work, so I found this class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Pointer < T >
{
    private Func<T> getter;
    private Action<T> setter;

    public Pointer ( Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter )
    {
        this.getter = getter;
        this.setter = setter;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return getter(); }
        set { setter(value); }
    }
}
```

Thanks to it I can assign values to value types like to reference like this:

```
int i = 1;
Pointer ptr = new Pointer<int>(()=>i, x=>{i=x;})
ptr.Value = 5;
Console.WriteLine(i);// prints as expected 5;
```

Works, but as you can see it is quite not elegant way (at least I think it is not).

So the question remains. What is the best practice in cases like this?

Cheers

Comment: create your own custom type aka class

Comment: Why on earth would you ever need to do that?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, this is not a case. I have planty of diffrent variables in code that client wants to be able to change via in-app console. Darin if you read my post you will find out, or you have just elegant way of doing it other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Official answer:**

You should never expose direct access to your members. The values you want to be modifyable should be in a container object (the model). All modifications of this model should be done by one authority (the controller).

**Inofficial answer:**

Using reflection, you'll be able to access even value type fields and get or set their values.

If this does not help I need a clearer understanding of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. If that is .NET principle, and using reflection is only way, then I would say this sucks and I stay with 'Pointer' class. Imagine my case: Client wants to be able to change player speed via in-app console, for balancing the game purposes. I have the speed controlled by some float in class 'Player'. So I just create one line of code adding new command into my console manager with "reference" to this float. Client changes the value in runtime via console, and checks how all works now. Doing this with reflection would be also possible but much more risky in my opinion.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Having a pointer to a class' private variable would be horrible design even in languages that use pointers. Why can't your player class have a method `SetSpeed` that gets called? That would be a good solution in any language, pointers or not.

Comment: Considering this use case I guess the best thing to do would be to have properties instead of fields, and to decorate those properties with a custom attribute that marks them as being modifyable by the console. Using reflection you can scan your Player class for modifyable properties and automatically add proper, type aware commands to your console. You can also add lots of metadata to your custom attribute, like a description, default, min and max values etc.

Answer (score -2):

It's not c# way. The simplest decision is create class with static fields and change it.

Comment: Well maybe I dont understand, but how it will help me adding fast new console commands, that will assign values from console to certain value types? With 'Pointer' class I can add command with just one line with "reference" to any int or float etc.